# Proper way to set up stack segment, base and stack pointers for x86 real mode for a given stack location and size?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, callstack

I am trying to initialize the `ss`, `sp`, and `bp` registers in x86 real mode. Given a stack growing downwards from physical address `B` upto a maximum size of `S` bytes, Is the following initialization procedure correct?

- Set `ss` to `(B - S) / 16`.
- Set `bp` to `S`, so that `ss:bp` is `B`.
- Set `sp` to `bp`, initializing an empty stack.

In the above I have assumed that `B - S` turns out to be a paragraph aligned physical address, and that `B` and `S` are both divisible by 2, so word alignment is guaranteed.

Comment: That does work.  Make sure to assign `ss` and `sp` in two consecutive instructions or disable interrupts beforehand or you might be in for a nasty race condition.  Note further that you can chose any convenient segment for `ss`.  It doesn't have to be normalised such that `ss:fffe` is the highest stack slot.

Comment: You always want to set SS then SP in that order in 2 consecutive instructions, unless you have interrupts disabled.  Setting SS defers interrupts until the end of the *next* instruction so you can atomically set SS:SP.  (Except for some old buggy steppings of 8086 that failed to implement that properly; hopefully these days we can ignore them.)   Or use `lds` to do it in one instruction, but 8086 didn't have that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suppose you mean `lss` not `lds`.